# 422 Unprocessable Entity, JS Files, gitlab 8.17, apache ssl

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, proxy, gitlab

yesterday a make a new gitlab 8.17.0 installation on ubuntu 16.04 installation and confgure it like the old one which I have documented. I am running a apache2 which letsencrypt as a proxy. It looks as if everything runs well, but a few JS files are not loaded. I get "422 Unprocessable Entity" https at

- domain/assets/webpack/application-XXX.js
- domain/assets/webpack/lib_dX.js
- domain/assets/webpack/users-X.js
- domain/assets/webpack/lib_d3-X.js
- domain/assets/webpack/users-X.js

**/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'

nginx['listen_address'] = 'localhost'
nginx['listen_port'] = 8080
nginx['listen_https'] = false

web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
nginx['enable'] = false
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab.example.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName gitlab.example.com
        ServerAdmin mail@gitlab.example.com

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.example.com/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.example.com/access.log combined

        Redirect 301 / https://gitlab.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName gitlab.example.com
        ServerAdmin mail@gitlab.example.com

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.example.com/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.example.com/access.log combined

        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.example.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.example.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.example.com/chain.pem

  <Proxy http://localhost:8080/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone have ideas to solve the problem?

Thank you! I wish you a nice Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with serving mentioned static files but behind nginx proxy. In */var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log* file there were errors:

```
Started GET "/assets/webpack/application-0b895f7016d93748393a-v2.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-05 11:14:21 +0100
Processing by ApplicationController#route_not_found as JS
  Parameters: {"unmatched_route"=>"assets/webpack/application-0b895f7016d93748393a-v2"}
Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript.
If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to
permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)

ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest (Security warning: an embedded 
<script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know 
what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to 
permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.):
  lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:93:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:16:in `call'
```

So I've made changes in */opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/environments/production.rb*:

```
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_files = true
```

and restarted gitlab (*gitlab-ctl restart*). Now it works, however I suppose that security of my server is weakened.

Comment: Congratulation. I reinstall gitlab in a old version. This was my solution. Everything now ist fine. Please also see this issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/2021

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in 8.17 thas hasn't been fixed yet.

Just downgrade to 8.16 `sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce=8.16.6-ce.0`